# how to register a video.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, video.js

I've been fooling around with videojs and I'd like to register a plugin for some code that I grabbed over on Github [my forked code](https://github.com/brendosthoughts/videojs-thumbnails). I followed the setup directions indicated by original author, however when the script goes to self register I get a javascript error on this line:

```
videojs.plugin('thumbnails', function(options) {
```

which gives error `Uncaught Reference error : videojs is undefined` I referred to the docs for videojs where it's says to register a plugin using the call

```
vjs.plugin('examplePlugin', examplePlugin);
```

seen at [this link](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/plugins.md). So I was hoping a quick fix would be to just change `videojs` to `vjs` but no such luck! Where am I supposed to declare `vjs/videojs` and as what? as it's not mentioned in the plugin docs. So basically how do you properly register plugins?

Comment: same question, anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Have you done the following?

```
<script src="/path/to/video.js"></script>
```

Doing this should include the necessary files that declare `vjs` and its extended name `videojs`.

These are both decalred in the above script.

Either `vjs` or `videojs` should work if you have done so.

Also, make sure that you have included `video.js` **before** your plugin registration. If you have done so, then I believe what you are doing should work fine.

According to the demo included in the vjs download, keep the script include for `video.js` in the `<head>` tags to be compatible with older browsers.